# Error executing the build in the app (cordova build android), after adding and configuring “cordova-plugin-bg-location-sender”

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins

Getting error while cordova build

ionic info
✔ Gathering environment info - done!

Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.2.1 (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.2
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
Cordova Platforms : android 7.1.2, browser 5.0.4
Cordova Plugins : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.5, (and 23 other plugins)

System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/hitesh/Android/Sdk)
NodeJS : v8.11.3 (/usr/bin/node)
npm : 6.4.1
OS : Linux 4.13

cordova plugin list

```
cordova-open-native-settings 1.5.1 "Native settings"
cordova-plugin-actionsheet 2.3.3 "ActionSheet"
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 2.0.1 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
cordova-plugin-bg-location-sender 2.1.2 "BGLocationSender"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.3 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.1 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-email-composer 0.8.15 "EmailComposer"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 2.4.6 "cordova-plugin-googlemaps"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.5 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-nativeaudio 3.0.9 "Cordova Native Audio"
cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder 3.1.3 "NativeGeocoder"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy 2.2.3 "Request Location Accuracy"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.3 "SocialSharing"
cordova-support-google-services 1.1.0 "cordova-support-google-services"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
mx.ferreyra.callnumber 0.0.2 "Cordova Call Number Plugin"
paywitheasebuzz-cordova-plugin 0.0.1 "easebuzz-cordova-kit"
phonegap-plugin-multidex 1.0.0 "Multidex"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.2.3 "PushPlugin"
uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator 4.2.2 "Launch Navigator"

:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /home/hitesh/Documents/IONIC/APPLICATIONS/Taxiwala/IN_taxiwala/platforms/android/app/google-services.json
:app:mergeDebugResources
[string/google_app_id] /home/hitesh/Documents/IONIC/APPLICATIONS/Taxiwala/IN_taxiwala/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml [string/google_app_id] /home/hitesh/Documents/IONIC/APPLICATIONS/Taxiwala/IN_taxiwala/platforms/android/app/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
[string/google_api_key] /home/hitesh/Documents/IONIC/APPLICATIONS/Taxiwala/IN_taxiwala/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml [string/google_api_key] /home/hitesh/Documents/IONIC/APPLICATIONS/Taxiwala/IN_taxiwala/platforms/android/app/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

[string/google_app_id] /home/hitesh/Documents/IONIC/APPLICATIONS/Taxiwala/IN_taxiwala/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml [string/google_app_id] /home/hitesh/Documents/IONIC/APPLICATIONS/Taxiwala/IN_taxiwala/platforms/android/app/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
[string/google_api_key] /home/hitesh/Documents/IONIC/APPLICATIONS/Taxiwala/IN_taxiwala/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml [string/google_api_key] /home/hitesh/Documents/IONIC/APPLICATIONS/Taxiwala/IN_taxiwala/platforms/android/app/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

BUILD FAILED in 23s
22 actionable tasks: 16 executed, 6 up-to-date
/home/hitesh/Documents/IONIC/APPLICATIONS/Taxiwala/IN_taxiwala/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

[string/google_app_id] /home/hitesh/Documents/IONIC/APPLICATIONS/Taxiwala/IN_taxiwala/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml [string/google_app_id] /home/hitesh/Documents/IONIC/APPLICATIONS/Taxiwala/IN_taxiwala/platforms/android/app/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
[string/google_api_key] /home/hitesh/Documents/IONIC/APPLICATIONS/Taxiwala/IN_taxiwala/platforms/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml [string/google_api_key] /home/hitesh/Documents/IONIC/APPLICATIONS/Taxiwala/IN_taxiwala/platforms/android/app/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

BUILD FAILED in 23s

Answer (score 0):

**I found a solution to a problem:**

Instructions similar to those I followed (and that caused the problem) are available here, although with the versions of the dependencies a bit outdated:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

What caused the problem in my case was to follow these instructions on the App creation page in Firebase and add the dependencies in the build.gradle files of the project and module as can be seen below:

Add in project build.gradle /project/platforms/android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter ()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        Google()
    }
    dependencies {

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // Firebase
        classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 4.0.0'
    }
}
```

And add in module build.gradle /project/platforms/android/app/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral ()
        jcenter ()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        Google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // Firebase
        classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 4.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase: firebase-core: 16.0.0'
    }
}

// Firebase, add at the end of the same file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

**Solution:**

The solution I found was to comment the lines that are preceded by the comment // Firebase:

File: /project/platforms/android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter ()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        Google()
    }
    dependencies {

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // Firebase
        // classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 4.0.0'
    }
}
```

File: /project/platforms/android/app/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral ()
        jcenter ()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        Google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

        // Firebase
        //classpath 'com.google.gms: google-services: 4.0.0'
        //classpath 'com.google.firebase: firebase-core: 16.0.0'
    }
}

// Firebase, add at the end of the same file
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

After these steps, everything worked fine and I was able to run `$ cordova build android` without problems.

---

**Suggestion:** If any other errors occur, try removing the plugins and platform, then re-create them:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-bg-location-sender --save
$ ionic cordova platform rm android

$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-bg-location-sender --save
$ ionic cordova platform add android
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your project directory, run:

`./gradlew clean build`

or from Android Studio select:

Build > Clean Project